# Google Spreadsheets, Insert a cell value to another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know anything about scripts so I would prefer a function.

I have a table like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |

**If "a1" = 1 a2 = today's date.**

For example:

- if I write to a1 cell a "1" it will "transform" into today's date,
- if anything else nothing happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put this formula in `A2` cell :

```
=if(A1=1,TODAY(),"")
```

Comment: Yeah, but then i cant write to it

Comment: So, can you please clarify what's the issue exactly?